# Jenkins interacting with the local Tomcat instance

Tags: tomcat, coldfusion, tomcat6, jenkins

I have Jenkins installed on my development server to run the following operations on my development codebases (written in ColdFusion):

- Pull down any changes from Git
- Create the new Host on Tomcat?
- Run all Unit tests
- If tests pass then create a Git tag to say that it was successful
- Else if tests fail then IM me

I am able to do everything, except for the second item in my list.  The first problem that I have is that I am not sure what the best practice is, create a new host in the workspace or copy the code to a directory somewhere else.

Jenkins and ColdFusion run on the same Tomcat server; Jenkins is running as WAR deployment and Railo (CF) runs on all hosts created on Tomcat, creating a WEB-INF directory there).

I was able to find plenty of documentation on deploying applications to remote Tomcat instances, but I couldn't find anything on deploying to a local Tomcat instance, so can I create Tomcat Hosts from Jenkins?  If so what is the best way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a Jenkins instance running doing much of the same. I think a simple solution would be to have a process append a new Host entry to the XML file. Since this is on the same machine, this should be really easy. You could do this with CFML, but, I try to put these processes in scripts (I use Scala which has great XML functionality and can easily be executed as a script) so they can execute without a dependency on the CFML engine.

1. Shutdown Railo (net stop railo)
2. Append a  entry.
3. Start Railo (net start railo)
4. Perform tests.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I build a simple Ruby app to do all of those processes, but I realized something when I went to use it; Jenkins is running on the Tomcat instance that is running, so it wouldn't notify me of issues unless I had one job to create the host and another to do everything else.  Instead I guess I'll just create each host myself and just point the jobs workspace to the host folder.

Comment: Perhaps you could migrate to a default Jetty install?

Comment: I was hoping to keep everything on 1 Tomcat instance.  I am just going to change my deployment flow to the following: 1) Create a new Tomcat host 2) Restart the Tomcat instance 3) Create the Job in Jenkins pointing the workspace to the new Tomcat host.  Seems a lot easier now that I think of it then what I was looking to do.

Comment: It is not an option to reinstall and reload an existing web application on the Tomcat with the latest war archive built by Jenkins? If so, that is quite easy. I wrote a guide on it here http://macgyverdev.blogspot.se/2014/02/how-to-make-jenkins-install-packaged.html